# How to extract a function from file?

Tags: grep, c, search

I am looking for a command to extract a C function from my code. It would be something like:

```
$ grep -func "MyFunction" foo.c

int MyFunction(int i) {
    return i+1;
}
```

I know we can extract it with a REGEX, but I am looking for something more friendly.

Comment: What do you want it to extract? The whole function? The header?

Comment: Given how complex the interior of a C function can be, I'm pretty sure you'd need some kind of extended regex (it should be possble with pcre's) and even then it will be hard to read as well as write.

Comment: Programming languages are *very* different, so making something that works for any language is impossible.

Comment: I have an answer that doesn't use a `regex`. I would post it but apparently this question is opinion-based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the file is syntactically correct, you could format it with `indent` and make the process for finding and extracting the function much simpler:

- with `indent`, you can make the function name in the first column of a line, followed by a left-parenthesis, and
- after that, the next right-brace `'}'` appearing in the first column would end the function.

Here is a simple example using GNU `indent` and `awk`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $1 = file name
# $2 = function name
indent -st -orig "$1" | awk '
BEGIN { state = 0; last = ""; }
$0 ~ /^'$2'\(/ { print last; state = 1; }
        { if (state == 1) print; }
$0 ~ /^}/ { if (state) state = 2; }
        { last = $0; }
'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the function header, you could use `ctags`:

```
$ ctags -x foo.c
MyFunction         1 foo.c            int MyFunction(int i) {
```